# Android Layout and positioning issue

Tags: java, android, android-layout

recently i'm building an app and now i have some problem with layout and positioning. in fact i build my layout but when i test on bigger screen everything collapsed and look of my app is not good. what is the best way to produce UI?

Comment: You need to check out http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: see multiple screen supports in developer.android.com

Comment: Post the possible XML layout code that you have tried so far.

Comment: thanks for reply, i check these links. thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [Supporting multiple screens.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Also, while creating UI, try to keep the layout as `RelativeLayout` and avoid hardcoding for `layout_height` and `layout_width`so that your UI will fit on all screens.
Happy Coding.